# Powershell get-scheduledjob to list jobs created by other users

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Somehow I can't see scheduled jobs created by another user with get-scheduled job (can see them using task scheduler in powershell\scheduledjobs). What is the trick? powershell v3.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what it is you are trying to do and what you've tried already?

Comment: if youre using admin account, the task scheduler would elevate/UAC prmpt/, unlike PS

Comment: Log in as user1, register-scheduledjob job1, execute it; can read job1 using get-scheduledjob, can see the corresponding files in $env:localappdata\microsoft\windows\powershell\scheduledjobs directory and in task scheduler.
Log in as user2, can see files in env:<user1>localappdata\microsoft\windows\powershell\scheduledjobs directory and job created by user1 in task scheduler; however, can't get them using get-scheduledjob. 
Let me know if additional info is needed.

Comment: I receive "Get-scheduledjob: A scheduled job definition...could not be found" error. Runing PS as Admin makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

I've got some solution for you.

As you notice you can see all Scheduled Job into Task Scheduler. So I Run :

```
Get-ScheduledTask
```

and then

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\"
```

So You can see all your PowerShell Jobs. I you really want ot retreive ScheduledJob objects then, you can run :

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Actions | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Arguments | % {$_ -match '^.*= (.*);.*$'; Invoke-Expression $Matches[1]}
```

I just put some glue to retreive the jobs from the launch of each task.